# Can't install TDA on R (Mac)

Tags: c++, r, topology

I'm trying to install the TDA on my Mac. Prior to this I tried phom but it was, I guess, out of date.

It tells me

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘TDA’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
```

then has a giant blob of red text after I accept, mentioning a whole bunch of files and saying

```
Warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push
```

a number of times for each block of text, then

```
all paths through this function will call itself
```

and

```
fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
```

but I went into terminal and had it install gmp, but that failed for some reason or another. Something about not finding a working compiler

Please help I'm trying to do my final project. I'm a mathematician who loves math and is terrible with computers and I've been fighting with a computer for the last 3 days on various final projects and I can't wait to get done with my applied semester and just go back to pure math and I'm probably going to cry.

Comment: Some very important information is missing, what version of R are you using? What version of OSX are you using? Reading the CRAN package it seems like you need C++ and gmp installed. Do you have these installed?

Comment: I'm using RStudio version 1.1.419
Mac OSX version 10.13.4
R version 3.4.3

A friend helped me get Dionysis running on Python so now I can do my work (and hence won't cry) but I'd still like to understand why I couldn't figure this out

Comment: Also I did brew install gmp but it seemed to complain about something related to having a compiler

Comment: Did you install Xcode and the Command Line Tools? (I have those, but the binary version of TDA for the Mac failed to install on my R version 3.4.3, possibly related to the recent change in R versions. However, I also tried installing from earlier source packages and got too many errors and the effort stopped.)

Comment: I feel like it's probably due to the recent change in R versions. It felt like all the documentation implied it should install very easily. And yeah I have XCode and I'm losing track of all the stuff I've installed trying to make things work, haha